# XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity in php webservices

Tags: php, xml, removing-whitespace

In My project, i am using xml for webservices. Currently running on Apache server and will be migrating it to Nginx server.

I am using same files as webservice pages on both servers. There is no problem on files on Apache server. The new Nginx server shows `"XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity"` on these pages.
While searching I found that there may be some extra space or lines just before the xml header or php tags. I checked each section and output an xml just after the php open tag.

I am sure that there is no additional space from my code page. But when I take it in browser and view source code, there is an extra line on top which causes the problem. And 
when I remove   ob_start() and use ob_clean()  just before calling xml it will work fine. But there are lots of such xml outputting pages on my webservice folder and it is not practical to insert  ob_clean() on 
each pages.

The nginx server providers made server settings almost similar to Apache environment like setting output_buffering, zlib module etc. But I suspect there may be some mismatch in server side arrangement on new server.

Anybody faced similar problem `"XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity"` due to the misconfiguration of any of the modules on your server?

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Never happened to me but [this](http://nils.realeyesmedia.com/?p=70) may help you:

"Finally, after asking someone for help, I thought to just look at Server Settings > Settings. There was the Enable Whitespace Management option. It was unchecked. I checked that and submitted the new settings and everything was right as rain."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.I forwarded the same to our server providing team

Comment: The solution you have found is only valid for coldfusion, but we cannot find it for nginx or even apache.This is the reply from my server providers